# .NET Core 2.0 Console App using Quartz.net 3.x and Sqlite 3.0

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, quartz.net

Trying to use Sqlite with Quartz scheduler 3.0.0-alpha3 with System.Data.Sqlite.Core (1.0.105.2) with the following configuration on a .NET Core 2.0 console application compiling on my Mac OSX Visual Studio:

```
NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection {
 { "quartz.threadPool.type", "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" },
 { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "10" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_" },
 { "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz" },
 { "quartz.dataSource.default.provider", "SQLite-10" },
 { "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", "Data Source=quartznet.db;Version=3;" }
};
```

**Actual behavior**

> Quartz.SchedulerException: Could not Initialize DataSource: SqliteDS
> ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: There is no metadata information for provider 'SQLite-10' Parameter name: providerName
>
> at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider.GetDbMetadata(String providerName) in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\Common\DbProvider.cs:line 118
> at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider..ctor(String dbProviderName, String connectionString) in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\Common\DbProvider.cs:line 74
> at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.d__65.MoveNext() in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 614
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.d__65.MoveNext() in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 623
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.d__69.MoveNext() in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 1118
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at BackgroundProcessingWithQuartz.Program.d__1.MoveNext() in /Users/jakesmith/Projects/BackgroundProcessingWithQuartz/BackgroundProcessingWithQuartz/BackgroundProcessingWithQuartz/Program.cs:line 44 [See nested exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: There is no metadata information for provider 'SQLite-10'
> Parameter name: providerName
> at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider.GetDbMetadata(String providerName) in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\Common\DbProvider.cs:line 118
> at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider..ctor(String dbProviderName, String connectionString) in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\Common\DbProvider.cs:line 74
> at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.d__65.MoveNext() in C:\projects\quartznet-6fcn8\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line 614

What I am missing? Everything is installed through NuGet on my Visual Studio for Mac. Plus why are there are references to the C Drive when the dll is actually running on a Mac. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

**Quartz 3.0 beta 1 supports Microsoft.Data.Sqlite out of the box**

Add required package references:

> PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="2.0.0" />
>
> PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.0.0-beta1" />

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static async Task Run()
    {
        var properties = new NameValueCollection
        {
            ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
            ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true",
            ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
            ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
            ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz",
            ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SQLite-Microsoft",
            ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Data Source=test.db",
            ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "binary"
        };


        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        IScheduler sched = await sf.GetScheduler();

        await sched.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }
}
```

**Registering custom provider metadata**

*Only needed if you want some other provider than Microsoft.Data.Sqlite or using version older than beta 1*

You need to register metadata first to be able to reference custom SQLite provider. Here's an example:

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.0.0-alpha3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            DbProvider.RegisterDbMetadata("sqlite-custom", new DbMetadata()
            {
                AssemblyName = typeof(SqliteConnection).Assembly.GetName().Name,
                ConnectionType = typeof(SqliteConnection),
                CommandType = typeof(SqliteCommand),
                ParameterType = typeof(SqliteParameter),
                ParameterDbType = typeof(DbType),
                ParameterDbTypePropertyName = "DbType",
                ParameterNamePrefix = "@",
                ExceptionType = typeof(SqliteException),
                BindByName = true
            });


            var properties = new NameValueCollection
            {
                ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true",
                ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
                ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
                ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz",
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "sqlite-custom",
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Data Source=test.db",
                ["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz",
                ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "binary"
            };


            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            IScheduler sched = await sf.GetScheduler();

            await sched.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        }
    }
}
```

You are seeing references to C drive due to the fact that the Quartz library was compiled on a Windows machine which will make the PDB files contain path from the build host machine.